# JavaScript class change onClick relocates image

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I am using a simple style rule:

```
.off { float: left; background: url(image.png); }
.on { background: url(different_image.png); }
```

in conjunction with a simple JavaScript event:

```
<a href="#">
<div class="off" onclick="this.className='on'; return false;">
link
</div>
</a>
```

In order to change an image in my navigation bar upon being clicked. To give a bit more insight, I am using an image of an "admit one" ticket for the link, with an image of a torn ticket appearing once clicked. Essentially, I want the action of tearing the ticket once clicked, not just while " :active " (that only applies while the mouse is still clicked down). I need the image to change, and presumably would use the " :visited " pseudo element (is that what that's called?) to have the ticket remain torn once visited.

My problem is this: The JavaScript seems to be functioning properly, except that when I click the link, my link moves from its floated position in the nav bar to some (seemingly, though not actually) random location near the top of my page.

It seems that the script ignores my CSS once it's clicked; what am I missing?

Do I need to specify a new set of rules, or duplicate them, for the "new" class? Does JavaScript actually change the element in its entirety? I suck with JS, but I have a very firm grasp on CSS.

Comment: Wouldn't adding `float: left; ` to your .on class resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need `float:left` on both.

```
.off { float: left; background: url(image.png); }
.on { float: left; background: url(different_image.png); }
```